# How to search on all fields with partial search string in spring data elastic search

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Suppose I have a word Pavan.I am able to get the data with complete word "Pavan",But when I am searching with "Pav".I am getting empty list.

Answer (score 1):

you can use queryString query ,it does full text search on all the fields or you can also specify the field in which u want to search manually
[please click this link for more information](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

```
@Autowired
private Client client;

   BoolQueryBuilder boolqueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

    boolqueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders
                    .queryStringQuery("*"+querystring+"*")
                    .defaultOperator(Operator.AND).analyzeWildcard(true));

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("your index name")

                .setQuery(boolqueryBuilder).setExplain(true).get();
```

Comment: May be the link mentioned has solution, but you should always put some essentials part here. some code preferably

Comment: Thanks for the solution